# Store a tree structure as a table

Tags: data-structures

Let me describe the one record structure in pseudo-code:

```
Record
 UserName
 E-mail
 Items[8]
   ItemPropertyA
   ItemPropertyB
   ItemPropertyC
   ItemPropertyD
   ItemPropertyE
```

There are 1-8 items in a record and exactly 5 properties each  in each item. So I need to store these many records as (excel) table and I want it to be human readable, if possible. The straitforward approach is to put items and properties in 8 * 5 = 40 columns, but this is difficult to review. I'm going to place a JSON array of properties in each cell (one celll per item), using as many cells in each rows as needed. I'm just curious about other tree-to-table possibilities.

Comment: why do you need 40 columns? you have up to 10 properties per record, so 10 columns

Comment: Fixed description.

Comment: json is not quite human readable format, 40 columns are much easier to view/sort/filter/etc

Comment: I'm talking about just one array `["foo", "bar"]`. Advantages: -the number of items can be seen easier; -the most important properties can be put first, so I'll see them right away; Disadvantages: you loose column names. But you don't see them anyway when scrolling down.

Comment: then just put `foo, bar` as value, why do you need braces and quotes?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to 40 separate columns (some of which may be unused if there are fewer than 8 items in a record).  You can use database style normalized records:

#### SHEET 1

```
RecordId UserName Email
       1 Bobby    bobby@example.com
       2 Susan    sueb@example.com
```

#### SHEET 2

```
RecordId ItemId PropertyA PropertyB PropertyC PropertyD PropertyE
       1      1 Chocolate Electric  Round     Silver    Hebrew
       1      2 Raspberry Steam     Trapezoid Brass     Esperanto
       1      3 Durian    Gravity   Bezier    Titanium  Bahasa Melayu
       2      1 Vanilla   Solar     Rhombus   Copper    Pashto
```

Of course you could normalize even further and have just a single Property column, but the above seems perhaps enough when you know each item has exactly the same five properties.